# Grabbing Object from mapped array React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to write a function that will save a specific object in an array that the user will click I am unsure of how to grab the data I need from the object

this is the function at the moment:

```js
saveArticle = event => {

    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId")
    event.preventDefault();
    const article = {
      title: this.title,
      summary: this.summary,
      link: this.link,
      image: this.image,
      userId: userId
    }
    console.log(article)
    // API.saveArticle()
  }
```

and this is the component where I map through the array

```js
const articleCard = props => {
    const { classes } = props
    return (
        <div>
            {props.articles.map((article, i) => {
                console.log(article);
                return (
                    <div key={i}>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardActionArea>
                            <CardMedia
                                className={classes.media}
                                image={article.image}
                                title={article.title}
                                href={article.link}
                            />
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography gutterBottom variant="headline">
                                    {article.title}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography component="p">
                                    {article.summary}
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </CardActionArea>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button href={article.link} size="small"                                      color="primary">
                                Read Article
                            </Button>
                            <Button onClick={props.saveArticle} size="small"                               color="primary">
                                Favorite
                            </Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I cant seem to grab the objects properties that I'd like to get and I am pretty lost as too how!

any help would be much appreciated thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Button onClick={(e) => props.saveArticle(article, e)} size="small" color="primary">
    Favorite
</Button>
```

and

```
 saveArticle = (article, event) => {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
    event.preventDefault();
    const article = {
      title: article.title,
      summary: article.summary,
      link: article.link,
      image: article.image,
      userId: userId
    };
    console.log(article);
    // API.saveArticle()
  };
```

---

Reference: [Passing Arguments to Event Handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)